# OpenGL. Обводка треугольника (triangle outlining) неправильная

Tags: c++, opengl

Функция рисования рисует два треугольника. Первый представляет собой фиолетовый треугольник, используется в качестве обводки. Другой — это уменьшённый в размерах «тот самый» обведённый треугольник.

Моя проблема заключается в том, что, во первых, ширина нижней часть обводки неравна другим сторонам, во вторых, если сместить камеру, то о нормальной обводке можно вообще не говорить.

Я использую функцию `glm::scale`, как и автор руководства, но не получаю результата. Как исправить программу, чтобы с любого положения у треугольника была обводка «одной ширины»?

```
void draw()
{   // draw outlined triangle
    glm::mat4 Projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(45.0f), (float)WINDOW_WIDTH / (float)WINDOW_HEIGHT, 0.1f, 100.0f);
    glm::mat4 View = glm::lookAt(
        glm::vec3(1, 0, 5),
        glm::vec3(0, 0, 0),
        glm::vec3(0, 1, 0)
    );
    glm::mat4 Model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    glm::mat4 mvp = Projection * View * Model;
    GLuint matrixId = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "mvp");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(matrixId, 1, GL_FALSE, &mvp[0][0]);
    GLuint colorId = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "inColor");

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glUniform4fv(colorId, 1, &outlineColor[0]);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    glUniform4fv(colorId, 1, &triangleColor[0]);
    Model = Model * glm::scale(Model, glm::vec3(0.9, 0.9, 0.9));
    mvp = Projection * View * Model;
    glUniformMatrix4fv(matrixId, 1, GL_FALSE, &mvp[0][0]);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
}
```

[image: обведённый треугольник]

[image: обведённый треугольник]

Comment: Сначала надо найти центр вписанной окружности треугольника, затем посредством transfrorm перенести начало координат в эту точку, только затем выполнить scale, а затем еще раз посредством transform перенести начало координат в нужное место. "автор руководства" - ¿какого еще руководства?

Comment: .. и все равно это не поможет если вы будете камеру вокруг треугольника крутить. При взгляде сбоку, обводка по бокам будет тонкой, а внизу не изменится.

Comment: Из этой https://learnopengl.com/code_viewer_gh.php?code=src/4.advanced_opengl/2.stencil_testing/stencil_testing.cpp - только он рисует кубики, а не треугольник. Возможно из-за этого ему не нужно ничего дополнительно перемещать? Но какую технику обводки обычно используют в играх? Я постоянно вижу реализацию обводки используя тест трафарета и функцию scale.

Comment: И то и то для обводки плохо, т.к. годится только для выпуклых моделей приближенных к кругу. Более хорошая обводка - либо геометрией вручную, либо с шейдерами (через промежуточную текстуру), либо широкими линиями (но их не все GPU корректно поддерживают).

Comment: Ладно, но они же умеют корректно их отображать (выпуклые объекты). Получается, что нужно наложить обводку только после обработки камеры?

Comment: Если говорить об обводке в экранном пространстве, то такой подход вполне сносно работает, только надо, чтобы фигура имела какой-то объем. А то если посмотреть с торца, то ее вообще же не будет видно.